# Boost::type_traits fundamental types and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, types

I can't get this to work. I want it to check for fundamental types but also for pointers of fundamental types:

```
template<typename T> struct non_void_fundamental : 
            boost::integral_constant<bool, 
                (boost::is_fundamental<T>::value && !boost::is_same<T, void>::value)
                || (boost::is_fundamental<*T>::value && !boost::is_same<*T, void>::value)
        >
        { };
```

Maybe some one can help me point me in the right direction.

Edit: It is especially the 4th line which doesn't do what I want, the rest works fine.

Edit 2: The point would be that it generates the following output in the following example:

```
int* p = new int(23);
cout << non_void_fundamental<double>::value << endl // true
cout << non_void_fundamental<some_class>::value << endl // false
cout << non_void_fundamental<p>::value << endl // true
```

Edit 3: Thanks to Kerrek SB, I have this know, but it is producing some errors.

```
template<typename T> struct non_void_fundamental : 
            boost::integral_constant<bool, 
                (boost::is_fundamental<T>::value && !boost::is_same<T, void>::value)
                || (boost::is_pointer<T>::value &&     boost::is_fundamental<boost::remove_pointer<T>::type>::value && !boost::is_same<boost::remove_pointer<T>::type, void>::value)
            >
        { };
```

Erros:

```
FILE:99:61: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in temp
late parameter list for 'template<class T> struct boost::is_fundamental'
FILE:99:61: error:   expected a type, got 'boost::remove_poi
nter<T>::type'
FILE:99:125: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in tem
plate parameter list for 'template<class T, class U> struct boost::is_same'
FILE:99:125: error:   expected a type, got 'boost::remove_po
inter<T>::type'
```

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: It's not about the error's it's generating. But more about the right approach, this definitely doesn't work. See my edit.

Comment: Are you sure `boost::is_fundamental<*T>` *isn't* supposed to be `boost::is_fundamental<T *>`? Same goes for `is_same<*T>`

Comment: Tried that too, doesn't generate errors, though it doesn't pass my example code

Comment: You should use `is_void`, which is the correct version of your own voidness check.

Comment: Thanks I'll replace that. Isn't the solution though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it the wrong way round, completely. Let's just concentrate on "`T` is a pointer to a fundamental type": That is:

- `T` is a pointer, and
- [`std::remove_pointer<T>::type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) is fundamental.

Now just put those all together. In pseudo-code:

```
value = (is_fundamental<T>::value && !is_void<T>::value) ||
        (is_pointer<T>::value && is_fundamental<remove_pointer<T>::type>::value)
```

In real code, Boost version:

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

template <typename T>
struct my_fundamental
{
    static bool const value =
      (boost::is_fundamental<T>::value && ! boost::is_void<T>::value) ||
      (boost::is_pointer<T>::value &&
       boost::is_fundamental<typename boost::remove_pointer<T>::type>::value);
};
```

In C++11, change the include to `<type_traits>` and `boost::` to `std::`.

Comment: You mean `remove_pointer` instead of `remove_reference` I quess. Thank you for your answer, this seems the right solution!

Comment: @Tim: I do, thanks! I never ever use `remove_pointer`, but `remove_reference` all the time, so my finger memory defeated me...

Comment: I get some error's know could you take a look at them (in the first post)?

Comment: @Tim: You need to say `typename`. Sorry, I thought that much was clear, since you've apparently been working with templates for quite a bit at this point -- that's why I said "pseudo-code" to not clutter up the presentation. But I realise that it's better to spell things out, which I've done now.